# RecyclerView onBindviewholder Dialog clicklistner Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have already created a `recyclerView` in which there is a `recycleview` `onBindView Holder` method i want to set there a dialog (Custom Dialog) in every `recyclerview` row there is a image and when i will click on the image of `recyclerview` a dialog will come by same image from bottom and when i click anywhere dialog should go down.

Note: Data coming in recylerview are from volley library

Comment: can you show me you code of Adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a custom dialog.

**dialog_image.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="270dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_iv"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="260dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

In `OnbindViewHolder()` of **Adapter class :**

```
 holder.medPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final Dialog dialogi = new Dialog(context);
                dialogi.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialogi.setCancelable(true);
                dialogi.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_image);
               // dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));


                ImageView dialogIv = (ImageView)dialogi.findViewById(R.id.dialog_iv);


                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(data.get(position).getMedicine_img_url().replace(" ","%20").trim())
                        .into(dialogIv);
                dialogi.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation_2; //style id
                dialogi.show(); 

                dialogIv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dialogi.dismiss();
                    }
                });


            }
        });
    }
```

In **Style.xml** Put this code :

```
 <style name="DialogAnimation_2">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
</style>
```

Inside **res** create a folder **anim** and within **anim** folder put there two animation res file :

**slide_up_dialog :**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toXDelta="0">
</translate>
```

**slide_out_down :**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="100%p">
</translate>
```

Comment: Thanks, Your answer working fine for my code. @Abhishek kumar